# Not opening or recognizing particular controller index mvc EntityModel 1st

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using model 1st approach.
My all controllers actions and views works fine But the last requirement of my project is to show 2 tables in view using same databaseTable.So i created a new view Model in my dataModel section. Now if I create a new controller for that particular class it shows me error **Can not Retrieve metadata for model class**. so finally I decided to create empty controller but when i navigate to that view it shows error **Resource not found 404**. Here is the code.

### Model class

```
    namespace BOL1
{
  public  class ADetailsVm
    {
        public List<BOL1.tbl_Transiction> Payables { get; set; }
        public List<BOL1.tbl_Transiction> Reciveables { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### DbContext

```
    public partial class bankingEntities : DbContext
    {
        public bankingEntities()
            : base("name=bankingEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<tbl_Accounts> tbl_Accounts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tbl_Transiction> tbl_Transiction { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tbl_TransictionType> tbl_TransictionType { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ADetailsVm> ADetailsVm { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
 public class Details : Controller
    {

        private TransictionBs objbs;
        public Details() 
        {
            objbs = new TransictionBs();
        }
        // GET: Shinwari/AccountDetails
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(int accountid)
        {
            ADetailsVm v = new ADetailsVm();
            //Load both the collection properties
            v.Payables = objbs.GetALL().Where(p => p.AId == accountid && p.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Payable")).ToList();
            v.Reciveables = objbs.GetALL().Where(r => r.AId==accountid && r.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Reciveable")).ToList();

            return View(v);
        }
```

### View

```
@model BOL1.ADetailsVm
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>AccountDetails</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table id="Payables" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Discription
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Payables)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Date
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.TDiscription
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Amount
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<table id="Reciveables" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Discription
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Reciveables)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Date
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.TDiscription
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Amount
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `Controller` suffix in your class to be considered as a controller class in the MVC pattern, which handles your incoming requests and return something.

```
public class DetailsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int accountid)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: u mean i should create controller class in my Model Class as well  ?

Comment: Who said that ? I am talking about renaming your details class in your question.

Comment: oh may bad :) It works now thank you very  very much

Comment: Shyju 1 more thing how can i total amount column ? i know  how to do it in gridview but not in mvc